# How to manage this project structure with git?

Tags: git, version-control

I'm developing addons for a web software which has its structure set up like this:

```
root
--index.php
--js/
----addon1/
------file.js
----addon2/
--css/
----addon1/
------style.css
----addon2/
--library/
----addon1/
------file.php
----addon2/
------file.php
```

I want to create a repository for each addon, but with the current structure it doesn't seem possible. The main chunk of the code for addon1 for example would be at /library/addon1/ and public assets for that addon would be at /js/addon1/. However if I set up the repository for addon1 at /library/addon1/ I cannot track the files outside in the js and css folders. Placing the repository one level up would mean I couldn't track each individual addon. Unfortunately I don't have the flexibility to move around the folders.

I have looked in to submodules, but I'm not sure that is what I need. There is no "main" or core repository as I don't need to track the main software, only my own individual addons that I create.

Is there any way to set this up?

Forgot to note that I don't need anything too complex as I only use these repositories locally and do not need to share them with anyone.

Comment: Why do you feel you need a separate repository for each addon. Is there a reason you cannot put all of this code in a single repository. Git is generally meant to encompass an entire project in a single repository.

Comment: @Glenn Each addon has its own features and its easier to manage each addon at a different version. Addon1 might be at version 1.2.1 whereas addon2 might be at version 1.1.0. I actually have everything in one repository right now and it's kind of a mess. Looking at the history also doesn't help when you only want to see recent changes for a certain addon.

Answer (score 0):

A simple architecture for this is to put the development of each addon in a branch.

Each addon can then be developed autonomously from the other addons. As you need more recent code from different addons due to dependencies, it is easy to use the git merge (with cherry-pick if needed) to bring those features into the correct branches.

Then, when you are ready to make a "stable" release, a "stable" commit from each addon branch can be merged into a release/trunk/master/stable (you can pick the name) branch. That way, each addon can be in a different stage of development, but code releases can still be assembled without stalling the development of any addon.

All within the same repository!

Comment: I think I tried this method before a long time ago and ran into some issues. The issues I see right now are that when I checkout a branch for an addon I can't see the development of the other addons unless I merge everything every time I make changes. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The idea of a branch is that you are developing a feature in isolation of development elsewhere. However, if you do need interdependency, you can merge the needed branches directly into your editing branch. For example, if I am working on widget1, and I need the updated version of widget2, I can merge the widget2 branch directly into widget1. Then, when I go to merge everything into master later, there will only be conflicts if I edit part of widget2 in the widget1 branch differently from how it progressed in widget2.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I like to be able to see all the latest changes. If I merge like you said, I would need to do it every time I make a change, which would be a hassle. I could also be working on up to 10 branches at once and it might become ugly with all the merges. I guess this kind of structure doesn't work well with git.

Comment: Managing ten different addons at different stages of development with interdependencies between all of the addons will be a hassle in any versioning system. It's just not the mindset for these tools.